# nvidia driver kernel module does not install itself upon a kernel update in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.15 (currently, it's 4.15.0-88-generic).

I also installed `nvidia-440` package from Nvidia official PPA.

It works fine until any kernel update. On such an update, it looks like nvidia driver module does not get installed. At least, after a reboot, I get a login screen in some low resolution (every screen element is a lot bigger than usual), and it is impossible to login. In the `dmesg` output, I don't see any mentions of nvidia (and before updating, in the working configuration, there are few such mentions during the boot).

So, after each update, I have to do the following: switch to console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), login there and then reinstall the driver with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-440`. After this (and then probably rebooting) it works fine.

With previous nvidia driver versions (which were not coming from a PPA), everything work fine: on each kernel update, kernel modules were automatically installed.

The questions follow:

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there a better way to fix the problem (probably, something that would work automatically, instead of requiring my manual intervention)?